# Does this code have a logic error?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and I am just starting to learn C++. I am trying to make a program that determines a person's net income after taxes; however, the program does not work properly. It compiles and runs, but it ends after asking for the "annual expenses."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    float grossIncome, expenses, adjustedGIncome, taxRate, taxAmount, netIncome; //Declaration of variables
    char again = 'y';
    while(again == 'y') //while loop used to rerun the program without having to recompile
    {
        system("reset");
        cout << "\nEnter your Gross Annual Income: "; //User enters his gross income
        cin >> grossIncome;
        cout << "\nEnter your annual expenses: "; //User enters his annual expenses
        cin >> expenses;

        adjustedGIncome = grossIncome - expenses; //gross income adjusted for taxes
        return adjustedGIncome;

        if (adjustedGIncome >= 415050) //if and else if statements used to determine tax percentage
        {
            taxRate = 0.396;
            return taxRate;
        }
        else if (adjustedGIncome >= 413350 && adjustedGIncome < 415050)
        {
            taxRate = 0.35;
            return taxRate;
        }
        else if (adjustedGIncome >= 190150 && adjustedGIncome < 413350)
        {
            taxRate = 0.33;
            return taxRate;
        }
        else if (adjustedGIncome >= 91150 && adjustedGIncome < 190150)
        {
            taxRate = 0.28;
            return taxRate;
        }
        else if (adjustedGIncome >= 37650 && adjustedGIncome < 91150)
        {
            taxRate = 0.25;
            return taxRate;
        }
        else if (adjustedGIncome >= 9275 && adjustedGIncome < 37650)
        {
            taxRate = 0.15;
            return taxRate;
        }
        else
        {
            taxRate = 0.1;
            return taxRate;
        }

        taxAmount = adjustedGIncome * taxRate; //tax amount determined so that the net income can be determined
        netIncome = adjustedGIncome - taxAmount; 

        cout << "\nAdjusted Gross Income: " << adjustedGIncome; //displays adjusted gross income
        cout << "\nTax Rate: " << taxRate; //displays tax rate depending on adjusted gross income
        cout << "\nTax Amount: " << taxAmount; //displays tax amount
        cout << "\n\nNet Income: " << netIncome; //displays net income
        cout << "\n\nRun this program again? (Y or N): "; //allows user to rerun program
        cin >> again;
        again =tolower(again);
    }
    system("reset");
}
```

Comment: you have the return statement return adjustedGIncome;

Comment: You seem to be confused between `return` and `break` and wrongly using `return` statements.

Comment: why are you using reset?

Comment: Makes no sense to return those values in main....

Comment: Makes no sense to use `break` either.

Comment: Simply remove _every_ `return` statements

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly using `return` statements in your code. A `return` statement passes control from the function back to whatever called it. In this case, you are exiting your main function.

The moment you reach this line `return adjustedGIncome;`, your program exits and will never progress beyond this point. Remove this line, and the similar `return` statements found in every branch of your `if/else` tree for determining tax rate. Remove them all.